# C# Object reference to another object's property

Tags: c#, .net, equality

Say I have an object's property pointing to different objects during its lifetime.

```
MyClassInstance.MyProperty = MyOtherObject1;
```

Later in the application I get this:

```
MyClassInstance.MyProperty = MyOtherObject2;
```

And so on. My understanding is that MyOtherObject1 and MyOtherObject2 will be pointing to the same address in memory, which I want to avoid. How can I make sure MyOtherObject1 and MyotherObject2 are 2 completely different entities?

Comment: I don't understand... Setting the _property_ to `MyOtherObject2` will not link it together with `MyOtherObject1`. Or what do you mean? They will only be pointing to the same memory address if they're classes and you do: `<type here> MyOtherObject2 = MyOtherObject1;`.

Comment: I think your 'problem' here is imaginary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `MyOtherObject1` and `MyOtherObject2` are different objects, making the `MyClassInstance.MyProperty` equal to them, will not result in these 2 being the same.

```
MyClassInstance.MyProperty = MyOtherObject1;
```

This means any changes to `MyClassInstance.MyProperty` will change `MyOtherObject1`, as they effectively point to the same memory space.

```
MyClassInstance.MyProperty = MyOtherObject2;
```

This means that `MyProperty` now points to the same memory space as `MyOtherObject2`. Changes to `MyProperty` will leave `MyOtherProperty1` unaffected.